# How can I have Rythmbox controls on Xubuntu desktop/Xfce?

Tags: sound, xubuntu, xfce, conky

In Ubuntu 12.04 with Unity, rythmbox basic controls (play,pause, next and previous song) were accessible on the desktop from the sound notification icon.

Now I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 with Xubuntu Desktop with Xfce upgraded to 4.10. I still use Rythmbox. Any way of setting up a similar feature on Xfce?

I tried the 'Now Playing' screenlet set to use Rythmbox, but it does not work and from what I've read, screenlets are discontinued. Even their website is unreachable.

Then I tried out conky scripts, but I have not come across a conky script for rythmbox controls. Anyone knows such a script?

Even if anyone could come up with short shell script or let me know terminal commands to
1) play
2) pause
3) goto next song
4) goto previous song

it would be much appreciated and I could either save it on the desktop or in a panel as executable file/icons, or create keyboard shortcuts to the scripts and use it that way!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the plugin from http://code.mendhak.com/rhythmbox-tray-icon/ which should help.